# Preventing UITableView.tableHeader to go under the navigationItem

Tags: uitableview, ios6

I have an UITableView with an UISearchBar set as the tableView.tableHeader.
I set the tableView.bounces = NO.

My problem is that if the user scrolls up the table, the tableHeader (searchbar) will hide under the self.navigationItem.

How can I prevent this? I want the tableHeader to always be on screen.

I am coding for iOS6.

Thanks

Nicola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use separate `uiview` for prevent this problem, set your search bar on top of the new `uiview`  and put your `tableview` under the search bar, so when ever you need to show `tableview` call the `uiview` also it scrolls under the search bar itself.

Thanks.